# Regex to match all unicode quotation marks

Tags: regex, unicode, quotes, character-properties

Is there a simple regular expression to match all unicode quotes? Or does one have to hand-code it like this:

```
quotes = ur"[\"'\u2018\u2019\u201c\u201d]"
```

Thank you for reading.

Brian

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python doesn't support Unicode properties, therefore you can't use the `Pi` and `Pf` properties, so I guess your solution is as good as it gets.

You might also want to consider the "false quotation marks" that are sadly being used - the acute and grave accent (`´` and `` `):`\u0060`and`\u00B4`.

Then there are guillemets (`« » ‹ ›`), do you want those, too? Use `\u00BB\u203A\u00AB\u2039` for those.

Also, your command has a little bug: you're adding the backslash to the `quotes` string (because you're using a raw string). Use a triple-quoted string instead.

```
>>> quotes = ur"[\"'\u2018\u2019\u201c\u201d\u0060\u00b4]"
>>> "\\" in quotes
True
>>> quotes
u'[\\"\'\u2018\u2019\u201c\u201d`\xb4]'
>>> quotes = ur"""["'\u2018\u2019\u201c\u201d\u0060\u00b4]"""
>>> "\\" in quotes
False
>>> quotes
u'["\'\u2018\u2019\u201c\u201d`\xb4]'
```

Comment: Not yet; there is a rewrite of the `re` module underway, but I have no idea when/if it will be merged into the main development branch. I doubt it will be there before Python 3.3.

Comment: Even if they aren't yet available in the `re` module, you can still import the `unicodedata` module and do `quotes = ''.join(c for c in (chr(i) for i in range(0x110000)) if unicodedata.category(c) in ('Pf', 'Pi'))`.

Answer (score 5):

Quotation marks will often have the Unicode category `Pi` (punctuation, initial quote) or `Pf` (Punctuation, final quote).  You'll have to handle the "neutral" quotation marks `'` and `"` manually.

Comment: +1: Man, I overlooked this. I have corrected my answer. Sadly, Python doesn't support Unicode properties (yet). He didn't specify Python, but I'm guessing this from his code sample and his previous question.